# Displaying an arbitrarily-sized image with rounded corners inside fixed-size block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to display an arbitrarily-sized image inside a fixed-size block. The image needs to have its corners rounded. The image must fill up the entirety of the block; if it is bigger or smaller than the block it must be resized, if the image's aspect ratio is different from the block's it must be cropped and centered vertically and horizontally.

So far I've tried:

- Rounding the corners of the block using CSS border-radius - image appears through the rounded corner in Opera ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm7nw/)).
- Rounding the corners of the image using CSS border-radius - rounded corners are removed by cropping.
- Rounding the block with the image as its background using CSS border-radius - image is not properly resized.

I would prefer a pure CSS solution, but JavaScript/jQuery solutions are also appreciated. I'm looking for solutions that will at least work across modern browsers and degrade gracefully on older browsers (square corners, image doesn't break out of the block, etc).

Comment: You'll have to read a little about image manipulation in PHP and then find the mathematical formula to properly resize the image.

Comment: This is still not fixed crossbrowser. You'll have to wait a bit. (Even if you did it, if you add some animations or transition or shadows to your elements, the image corner will sometimes pop over )

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thankfully I don't need any animations, transitions or shadows on these elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfJyq/2/)** I made?

The idea is to use the `background-size: cover;` CSS property which handles the centering, cropping and, well, covering. Here's an extract from the fiddle:

```
div.yourWrapper {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: url('some_image.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I have no idea how this downgrades in IE and seriously, supporting Opera is just wrong due to [extremely low market adoption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29#Market_adoption) (but that's my personal opinion, you can start yelling at me now).

Comment: Works fine in Opera, IE8 nice, just missing the border-radius that results in smaller stretched images, but fine.

Comment: Opera has a significant market share in Russia (more than any other browser by some estimates, including IE), which is the target audience for the site being developed. It's also a great browser with loads of innovation behind it (Tabbed browser? Mouse gestures? That's all Opera). Anyway, great answer!

Comment: Looks like there's a bug in Opera that borks this solution in some cases, here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/crrYa/ Going to roll with this for now and hope that it gets fixed or another solution comes up.

Comment: Pfff, Opera. What a buggy browser :)

Comment: Uhm... I just tried that fiddle in Opera and it looks exactly the same as in Chrome. What's the issue?

Comment: I see an image fitting a div having rounded corners (°_° ). That's exactly what you wanted... no?

Comment: I want perfectly round corners, not ones cut off on the left and right sides of the image.